# GA: New user vs returning user

Tags: google-analytics

[image: GA screenshot]

The above is a screenshot from my GA account, behavior -> New vs Returning

What I don't understand is why `114,875` appears to be the number of new visitors as well as the number of total users (or at least it seems to be). Sometimes it is 85.49% and sometimes it is 100%. It is totally confusing at first glance. Why would google do this?

Answer (score 3):

The same user can be both New and Returning in a given date range, if they visited more than once and their first-ever visit is included. Since the date range in your screenshot appears to go back to the beginning of your analytics tracking, every user's first visit will be included - so every user will count as New, and those that visited more than once will also count as Returning.

If the metric in the table were Sessions instead of Users, then the numbers would add up to the column total.